# Isomorphic projective subvarieties, non-isomorphic rings

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space

If $S \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ is a closed set (in the Zariski sense) then $\mathcal{I}(S) \subset k[x_0,\ldots,x_n]$ denotes the homogeneous ideal of polynomials which vanish at $S$.

I want to find an example of two projective subvarieties $X \subseteq \mathbb{P}^n$ and $Y \subseteq \mathbb{P}^m$ such that $X \cong Y$ but $k[x_0,\ldots,x_n] / \mathcal{I}(X) \not\cong k[x_0,\ldots,x_m] / \mathcal{I}(Y)$. Here, a subvariety is irreducible, so $\mathcal{I}(Y),\mathcal{I}(Z)$ are necessarily prime (I think?)

I'm not looking for straight answers, but a hint is very welcome.

Comment: Take for $X$ and $Y$ a line and an irreducible  conic in $\mathbb P^2$.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly the hint I needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To turn Georges comment into an answer, the precise choices of homogeneous ideals in $S=k[x,y,z]$ could be $I = (xz-y^2)$ and $J=(x)$. Clearly, the two quotients are not the same because $S/I$ has dimension $3$ in degree $1$ and $S/J$ does not. However, you should be able to prove $\mathbb P^1\cong C:=\mathcal V(I)$ by mapping 
\begin{align*}
[u:v] &\longmapsto [u^2:uv:v^2].
\end{align*}
Note that on $u=1$, we have $[1:v]\mapsto [1:v:v^2]$, which is indeed injective. This is not a full proof to show that the two are isomorphic, but you should be able to go from here and glue functions on affine patches in both directions to get isomorphisms.

Comment: Yes, this is indeed the example I worked out, thank you very much!